# How to Map lat lng values in a dynamodb item with the javascript SDK

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I need to store a list of lat lng values into a dynamodb property, but I'm having trouble.  Do I set it as a "L" list type or do I need to map a more complex object in the dynamodb item declaration?

```
           var locations = [{lat:30,lng:20},{lat:20,lng:50}]

           dynamodb.putItem({
                "TableName": 'locations-history',
                "Item": {
                    "locations": {"L": locations},
                    "date": {'N': new Date().getTime().toString()}
                }
            }
```

which gives me the error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "error putting item into dynamodb failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'datatype' of undefined"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing annotations for your location list, if you want to use the low-level SDK you must annotate all fields within the location with "S" and "N" and "M". This quickly becomes ugly and verbose so you should look into using the [AWS Document Client](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk) which eliminates the need to annotate your JSON blobs, so your code would work like:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var DOC = require("dynamodb-doc");

AWS.config.update({region: "us-west-1"});

var dynamodb = new DOC.DynamoDB(); 

var locations = [{lat:30,lng:20},{lat:20,lng:50}]

dynamodb.putItem({
    "TableName": 'locations-history',
    "Item": {
         "locations": locations,
         // need to be number type for DDB to store it as a number
         "date": new Date().getTime() 
    }
}
```